# (ir)reducibility of projective representation when restricted to abelian subgroup

Tags: rt.representation-theory, group-cohomology

I am looking for a finite group $G$ and an irreducible projective representation $\rho: G \to PGL(\mathbb C^n)$ such that for *any* abelian subgroup $A\subset G$, the restricted representation $\rho|_A$ is reducible.

(EDIT: Moreover $\rho$ should be a `genuine' projective representation, in the sense that it represents a non-trivial cohomology class. In other words I am not allowing $\rho$ to be equivalent to a linear representation.)

More prosaically, I'm looking for a projective representation that is truly dependent on the non-abelian structure of the original group.

Of course it would be nice if the example were not a horribly complicated group; the 'simpler' the better. Alternatively I would of course greatly appreciate if someone could get me on the way to derive such an example myself.

Comment: I'm not sure you have posed the question you really intended. What about the 3-dimensional irreducible complex representation of $A_{5}$, which restricts reducibly to every Abelian subgroup?

Comment: Like @GeoffRobinson I am a bit puzzled by the emphasis/wording of the question. "Most" representations of an abelian group are reducible, at least in charcteristic zero...

Comment: I might be overlooking something, but isn't it more non-trivial since I'm asking about projective representations? Abelian groups generically have non-trivial irreducible projective representations.

Comment: @RubenVerresen, it sounds like you want a 'genuineness' condition, to ensure that your projective representation is not just the projectivisation of a linear representation.

Comment: It is true that non-cyclic Abelian groups can have irrreducible projective representations of degree greater than one (eg, a Klein 4-group has an irreducible projective representation of degree $2$). Nevertheless, the given representation of $A_{5}$ I mentioned does give an example of what the question asked.

Comment: Ah my apologies! Indeed you were right, I wasn't posing the question I had intended. I am not allowing $\rho$ to be a linear representation, otherwise it would indeed be a trivial question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The group ${\rm SL}(2,7)$ has a faithful complex irreducible representation of degree $4$. Viewing this as a projective representation of $G = {\rm PSL}(2,7)$ gives an example where every Abelian subgroup of $G$ acts reducibly, but $G$ acts irreducibly. This is because the only non-cyclic Abelian subgroups of $G$ are Klein $4$-groups, and the largest degree of a complex irreducible projective representation of a Klein $4$-group is $2$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any intuition as to whether this is one of the smaller groups with such a property? Is it for example clear whether or not it could work for $G = \mathcal A_5$?

Comment: I think it works with $A_{5}$ by a similar argument, but not with its $2$-dimensional projective representation, but once again with a $4$-dimensional  projective representation which is faithful for ${\rm SL}(2,5).$

Comment: Interesting. So do you mean that any non-cyclic Abelian subgroup of $A_5$ is a Klein 4-group?

Comment: Indeed to answer my own question: the subgroups are listed in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry which shows that the only abelian subgroups are either cyclic or of order 4 (note that one should only look at the part of the table in the purple hue, as they correspond to the chiral symmetry group of the icosahedron, which is $\mathcal A_5$)

Comment: I have just seen the question:  the answer is yes, as you have already by now seen in wikipedia,  since the only non-cyclic Abelian subgroups of $A_{5}$ are again Klein 4-groups.

Comment: Actually I think it might not work: $H_2(A_5;\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z_2$ whereas we already know $A_5$ has a non-trivial two-dimensional projective rep, so this means the four-dimensional one must not be a genuine proj rep(?)

Comment: Could I check two things? (1) Is my above argument correct as to why it shouldn't work for $A_5$? (2) Apparently $H_2(PSL(2,7);\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z_2$, moreover it seems the only faithful irreps of $SL(2,7)$ have dimension $4,4,6,6$. So does this mean these define four non-trivial projective representations of $PSL(2,7)$, moreover they all correspond to the same cohomology/Schurr class?

Comment: Your first comment about $A_{5}$ is not correct. The $4$-dimensional representation I am using is a genuine $4$-dimensional irreducible representation of ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ ( which is a maximal perfect central extension of $A_{5}).$ This may be viewed as an irreducible projective representation of $A_{5},$ but is no scaleable to an ordinary representation. I am NOT using the $4$-dimensional genuine irreducible representation of $A_{5}$ in this construction.

Comment: ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ has faithful irreducible characters of degree $2,2,4$ and $6$ which all yield projective representations of $A_{5}$ which do not come from genuine representations of $A_{5}.$

Comment: By the way, the faithful complex irreducible representations of ${\rm SL}(2,7$ have degrees $4,4,6,6,8$. To check: the sum of the squares of the degrees of these representations should be $168$.

Comment: These representations do indeed yield projective representations of ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ which are not equivalent to ordinary representations, but are all associated to the unique non-trivial cocycle of ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$.

Comment: I see, thank you. So it must be the case that the four-dimensional projective rep you talk about is simply in the same class as the two-dimensional one? Or are you saying $H_2(A_5;\mathbb Z) =  \mathbb Z_2$ is wrong?

Comment: No, the Schur Multiplier is correct. By the way, the order of the Schur multiplier is not usually connected in a straightforward way to the number of projective representations associated to a given $2$-cocycle.